# Calculate average using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join

How do I calculate the Average salary per location in Spark Scala with below two data sets ?

File1.csv(Column 4 is salary)

```
Ram, 30, Engineer, 40000  
Bala, 27, Doctor, 30000  
Hari, 33, Engineer, 50000  
Siva, 35, Doctor, 60000
```

File2.csv(Column 2 is location)

```
Hari, Bangalore  
Ram, Chennai  
Bala, Bangalore  
Siva, Chennai
```

The above files are not sorted. Need to join these 2 files and find average salary per location. I tried with below code but unable to make it.

```
val salary = sc.textFile("File1.csv").map(e => e.split(","))  
val location = sc.textFile("File2.csv").map(e.split(","))  
val joined = salary.map(e=>(e(0),e(3))).join(location.map(e=>(e(0),e(1)))  
val joinedData = joined.sortByKey()  
val finalData = joinedData.map(v => (v._1,v._2._1._1,v._2._2))  
val aggregatedDF = finalData.map(e=> e.groupby(e(2)).agg(avg(e(1))))    
aggregatedDF.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("output.txt")
```

Please help with code and sample output how it will look.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use DataFrame API, this should work:

```
val salary = sc.textFile("File1.csv")
               .map(e => e.split(","))
               .map{case Seq(name,_,_,salary) => (name,salary)}
               .toDF("name","salary")

val location = sc.textFile("File2.csv")
                 .map(e => e.split(","))
                 .map{case Seq(name,location) => (name,location)}
                 .toDF("name","location")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

salary
  .join(location,Seq("name"))
  .groupBy($"location")
  .agg(
    avg($"salary").as("avg_salary")
  )
  .repartition(1)
  .write.csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: So here the final output looks like below ?

+------------------------+
| location  | avg_salary |
+------------------------+
| Bangalore | 40000      |
| Chennai   | 500000     |
+------------------------+

Comment: One more doubt.. Suppose instead of salary, the column has dimensions like 600*200(length * width), how do i find average in this case ? Ram 600*200 Hari 700*300 and so on...

Answer (score 5):

You can read the CSV files as DataFrames, then join and group them to get the averages:

```
val df1 = spark.read.csv("/path/to/file1.csv").toDF(
  "name", "age", "title", "salary"
)

val df2 = spark.read.csv("/path/to/file2.csv").toDF(
  "name", "location"
)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val dfAverage = df1.join(df2, Seq("name")).
  groupBy(df2("location")).agg(avg(df1("salary")).as("average")).
  select("location", "average")

dfAverage.show
+-----------+-------+
|   location|average|
+-----------+-------+
|Bangalore  |40000.0|
|  Chennai  |50000.0|
+-----------+-------+
```

[UPDATE] For calculating average dimensions:

```
// file1.csv:
Ram,30,Engineer,40000,600*200
Bala,27,Doctor,30000,800*400
Hari,33,Engineer,50000,700*300
Siva,35,Doctor,60000,600*200

// file2.csv
Hari,Bangalore
Ram,Chennai
Bala,Bangalore
Siva,Chennai

val df1 = spark.read.csv("/path/to/file1.csv").toDF(
  "name", "age", "title", "salary", "dimensions"
)

val df2 = spark.read.csv("/path/to/file2.csv").toDF(
  "name", "location"
)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType

val dfAverage = df1.join(df2, Seq("name")).
  groupBy(df2("location")).
  agg(
    avg(split(df1("dimensions"), ("\\*")).getItem(0).cast(IntegerType)).as("avg_length"),
    avg(split(df1("dimensions"), ("\\*")).getItem(1).cast(IntegerType)).as("avg_width")
  ).
  select(
    $"location", $"avg_length", $"avg_width",
    concat($"avg_length", lit("*"), $"avg_width").as("avg_dimensions")
  )

dfAverage.show
+---------+----------+---------+--------------+
| location|avg_length|avg_width|avg_dimensions|
+---------+----------+---------+--------------+
|Bangalore|     750.0|    350.0|   750.0*350.0|
|  Chennai|     600.0|    200.0|   600.0*200.0|
+---------+----------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Suppose instead of salary, the column has dimensions like 600*200(length * width), how do i find average in this case ? Ram 600*200 Hari 700*300 and so on...

Comment: @akrockz, please see expanded answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Leo C.. This is what I was looking for.. One final request.. Currently I dont have Spark setup in my laptop.. Is it possible for you to send me the output if I mail you my input data ?
Sorry for asking too much.. Thanks

Comment: @akrockz, it's against my system usage policy running code or using data from unknown sources.  Sorry I can't help you on this.

Comment: If finally i want to write to a csv file, can i give below command ?
dfAverage.repartition(1).write.csv("output.csv")
Will this work ?

Comment: That'll do it.  Or you could replace repartition(1) with coalesce(1) to avoid data shuffle imposed by repartition().

Answer (score 2):

I would use dataframes:
First read the dataframes such as:

```
val salary = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("File1.csv")
val location = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("File2.csv")
```

if you don't have headers you would need to set the option to "false" and use withColumnRenamed to change the default names.

```
val salary = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv("File1.csv").toDF("name", "age", "job", "salary")
val location = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv("File2.csv").toDF("name", "location")
```

now do the join:

```
val joined = salary.join(location, "name")
```

lastly do the average calculation:

```
val avg = joined.groupby("location").agg(avg($"salary"))
```

to save do:

```
avg.repartition(1).write.csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Suppose instead of salary, the column has dimensions like 600*200(length * width), how do i find average in this case ? Ram 600*200 Hari 700*300 and so on...

Comment: what do you mean? do you mean multiple occurances of each name with multiple columns for each name?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
val salary = sc.textFile("File1.csv").map(_.split(",").map(_.trim))
val location = sc.textFile("File2.csv").map(_.split(",").map(_.trim))
val joined = salary.map(e=>(e(0),e(3).toInt)).join(location.map(e=>(e(0),e(1))))
val locSalary = joined.map(v => (v._2._2, v._2._1))
val averages = locSalary.aggregateByKey((0,0))((t,e) => (t._1 + 1, t._2 + e),
        (t1,t2) => (t1._1 + t2._1, t1._2 + t2._2)).mapValues(t => t._2/t._1)
```

then `averages.take(10)` will give:

```
res5: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Chennai,50000), (Bangalore,40000))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Suppose instead of salary, the column has dimensions like 600*200(length * width), how do i find average in this case ?
Ram 600*200  
Hari 700*300   
and so on...

Comment: Are the dimensions given as a String? Do you want to average the area (length multiplied by width) or have an average for each of these dimensions?

Comment: i want to have an average for each of these dimensions, group by location..